# infinite loop issue in my code : my programm seems not stopping

Tags: java

/* i have this file containing this data:
  San Francisco: 19887.32
  Chicago:  no report received
  New York:  298734.12
  Los Angelos: no report received
And i want to print just the cities
this is my code but seems like it's not stopping!*/

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("sales.dat"))) {

        String line;
        char c;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            do{
                c =(char) br.read();
                System.out.print(c);
            }while(c != ':');
            System.out.println();

        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
    }
```

Comment: It's likely hanging on the inner loop for some reason. Have you stepped through your code and seen the behaviour of the inner while?

Comment: @CanadianCoder I expanded my answer to explain why the infinite loop :-)

Comment: If you have a new question, then create a new one. Don't edit your existing question, or the current answers will become meaningless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code won't be doing what you need anyway, because it would skip every 2nd line. Do this instead:

```
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("sales.dat"))) {

        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            int i = line.indexOf(':');
            if (i != -1)
                System.out.println (line.substring(0, i));
        }
    }
```

And about the infinite loop: It does so because read() will return -1 when at the end of the file.

Comment: thanks it worked but i don't understand why it skip every 2nd line in my code?

Comment: because you're reading a line, and then you're reading chars from the same input. So the line (which would already have a ":") would be lost.

Comment: @KhatabBouchra as Tom said, create a new one. It is free :-)  (However do also learn to use a debugger, you'll learn more)

Comment: like what kind of debugger can i use for java?i think eclipse have a debugger but i guess i have to learn how to use a debugger.Thanks for your help and for the tip i appreciate it

Comment: @KhatabBouchra I use netbeans, but I'm sure that eclipse has also a debugger. Look at the menus... or search youtube for tutorials (youtube has more than cute cat videos!). I entered "eclipse debugger" in youtube and found lots of hits. Good luck!

Comment: @ TilmanHausherr thank you so much , i will definitely search for youtube tutorials about eclipse debugger .have a great day and thanks again for the help